# Graph with large visual-nodes (list of av-tuples)?

Tags: python, networkx

I want to create graph where the nodes are large squares listing several attribute-value pairs.

```
[  a1 : v1 ]    [  a1 : v1 ]
[  a2 : v2 ]----[  a5 : v1 ]
     |
     |
[  a3 : v1 ]
[  a4 : v2 ]
```

how do I do that in networkx ?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand.  Can you explain in more detail what you want a node to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question, what you want to do is to customize the shape and the labels of the nodes.

The shape can be customized with the *node_shape* parameters in the [draw_networkx_nodes](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.7/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes.html) function.
To customize the labels you can use the *label* parameter in [draw_networkx_labels](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_labels.html) function.

Consider the following example:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

graph = nx.grid_graph(dim=[2,2])

labels = {}
labels[(0,0)] = "a1:1\nb1:1"
labels[(0,1)] = "a2:2\nb2:2"
labels[(1,0)] = "a3:3\nb3:3"
labels[(1,1)] = "a4:4\nb4:4"


pos = nx.spring_layout(graph)

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(graph, pos=pos, node_shape="s", node_size=500)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(graph, pos=pos)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(graph, pos=pos,labels=labels, font_size=8)

plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

which outputs:
[image]